# How to leave the execution of a very heavy task in queue (running in the background) when closing the browser?

Tags: php, ajax, server, cron, host

this time I come with a question that I hope you can guide me to solve.
I have created a PHP script that allows loading a CSV file with a large amount of data (to load it I use the AJAX request). This script extracts the data from the file, then checks that this data is not already stored in the database, makes use of another script to obtain information of each data that is extracted from the file and finally saves the data that has passed successfully. all that validation process in a BD table.
It is a process that can last a few seconds or many minutes, because there are files that I can upload that contain more than 100 thousand data, so I would not like to leave the browser open all the time the process lasts.

What I want to know is how I could leave this process running internally on the server when I close the browser. Something like putting it in queue and let it continue running when I close my browser.
Once I reopen the browser and open the page of the script that shows me how the process is currently going. The idea is that the data processing is not interrupted when I close my browser.

Any suggestions or examples you could give me to achieve this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php could be a starting point

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you'd better run a dedicated daemon (either a 3rd party one or one written by yourself) yourself which does the background stuff.

The rationale behind why I don't think it right to do that in your PHP code is:

- If you fork it from your server code, you have to install something else and since it is a folk, that process you are gonna spawn will inherit some data not useful at all from the parent process
- With a dedicated daemon, it's easier for you to track the status of each job and more importantly, not a bunch of processes will be spawned if you just fork a new process for each job in the server code.

Comment: I agree on this - Create a table that holds data from the user request, and then a daemon/cron job to check for unprocessed requests every X minute.

Comment: I was thinking about it too. I'll try to do it, although I'm not very familiar with working with deamon / cron. So, What kind of data of the request would be necessary to store in the database, which allows me to resume the work where it has stopped.?

Comment: @RolandF, a daemon is always running in the background if it works as expected. If you are concerned about how to resume your work when the daemon accidentally dies or is forced to die for some reason, then you should consider storing the data you get from ajax calls somewhere and deleting them when the job is done.